# Marklogic MLCP with option -query_filter

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I have a xquery and want use MLCP with option -query_filter.  MLCP tool spool out errors look like it doesn't accept option -query_filter.  please give me some hints or example.  Thanks in advance. Thichxai

step 1 - I created a query "filter-activity.xqy" below for testing purpose
   xquery version "1.0-ml";

```
 fn:doc(cts:uris((),
                 (),
                 cts:collection-query('/activity-all')
                )            
 )
```

step 2 - I create a text file "export-activity.txt" contains MLCP EXPORT options below

```
 -username
  admin
 -password
  admin
 -host
  localDEV
 -mode
  local
 -database
  DEV
 -copy_collections
  true
 -copy_permissions
  true
 -query_filter
  filter-activity.xqy
 -output_file_path
  /output/export/data
```

Step 3 - Execute MLCP

```
 ./mlcp-8.0-5/bin/mlcp.sh EXPORT -options_file /output/export-activity.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `-query_filter` option requires the actual query.

The query needs to be serialized.

Full documentation here:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/export#id_66898

For you, The query would be:

```
...
-query_filter
<cts:collection-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts"><cts:uri>/activity-all</cts:uri></cts:collection-query>
...
```

You can derive that by running this in QConsole:

```
document { cts:collection-query("activity-all") }
```

But then again - based on your sample query - I would suggest you just use `-collection_filter` on the collection name instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  If a query have multiple clauses condition